# Как в переменную php записать структуру в html + echo?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Есть сайт на **wordpress**. Интересует как в `php` переменную записать вывод `html` и содержимое *echo*.
Пробую так:

```
<?php $s = '<p><a class="lostpassword" href="'. echo wp_lostpassword_url(). '">'. _e('Lost Password', 'memberdeck') . '</a></p>'; ?>
```

и пробую так:

```
<?php $s = '?><p><a class="lostpassword" href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url() ?>"><?php _e('Lost Password', 'memberdeck') ?></a></p><?php '; ?>
```

не получается..

Comment: Не знаю, кто заминусовал вопрос. Вопрос правильный, но несколько невнятно сформулирован. Поставил плюс, чтобы скомпенсировать.

Comment: @KAGG Design благодарю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для записи вывода в строку в php есть средства работы с буфером вывода.

```
ob_start();
// любой код php с выводом на экран
$s = ob_get_clean();
```

В результате выполнения этого кода весь планируемый вывод на экран попадёт в строку $s.

В применении к вашему коду (насколько я понял вопрос), должно выглядеть так:

```
ob_start();
echo '<p><a class="lostpassword" href="'. wp_lostpassword_url(). '">'. __('Lost Password', 'memberdeck') . '</a></p>';
$s = ob_get_clean();
```

А можно ещё проще:

```
$s = '<p><a class="lostpassword" href="'. wp_lostpassword_url(). '">'. __('Lost Password', 'memberdeck') . '</a></p>';
```

Функцию `_e()` надо заменить на `__()`, потому что первая производит вывод, а вторая - просто возвращает строку.

Comment: что-то не очень понимаю.. Вот так не работает

 `ob_start();
 echo wp_lostpassword_url();
 $s = ob_get_clean();
        $find = '<p><a class="lostpassword" href="'. $s . '">'. _e('Lost Password', 'memberdeck') . '</a></p>';`

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();
echo '<p><a class="lostpassword" href="'. wp_lostpassword_url() . '">'. _e('Lost Password', 'memberdeck') .'</a></p>';
$s = ob_get_clean();
```

вот так должно работать, пробуйте

Comment: взяли и убрали `echo`.. с какой целью?

Comment: echo в переменную не записываеться

Comment: это не ответ...

Comment: @Вася присоединяюсь к вышесказанному ответу, echo действительно не нужно

Comment: @Вася не пойму зачем вы минусуете корректный ответ. Уважаемый автор ответа дает вам совершенно точный ответ. Убрали echo потому что эта конструкция там не нужна.

Comment: @zalex кто минусовал? Я никого не минусовал. Это мой вопрос зачем-то минуснули просто так

Comment: @Антон Новерко уже лучше, но внутри `echo` вот эту конструкцию не разбирает `_e('Lost Password', 'memberdeck')`

Comment: @Вася в каком файле вы пытаетесь вывести свою переменную?

Comment: @Вася могу ошибаться, но дело в файле 'memberdeck'

Comment: @АнтонНоверко ну какой файл. Почитайте про функции getttext и интернационализацию WordPress

Comment: @АнтонНоверко ваш ответ не работает, потому что вы не знаете, что такое функция `_e()` (а найти её легко в Google). Она выводит перевод.

Comment: @KAGGDesign я написал что могу ошибаться, ваш комментарий я принял и постараюсь разобраться с этим вопросом, благодарю.